# Why is an error thrown in Python cryptography RSA decryption of encrypted AES key?

Tags: encryption, rsa, aes, asn.1

I am trying to decrypt an AES key from a DER-encoded file that has been encrypted in RSA format. With the following code:

```
         for key, value in configfile['File Extensions'].items():
            if filename.endswith(value):
                pemFile=r'C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\pkcs7.pem'
                with open(pemFile,'r') as f:
                    pem = f.read()
                # remove the -----BEGIN PKCS7----- header/footer
                    pemsplit=pem.split('\\n')
                    j =''.join(pemsplit[1:-2])
                    env_der = base64.b64decode(j)
                #print(env_der)
                    f.closed

      # merge files and then compare
                    content, rest = decode(env_der, asn1Spec=rfc2315.ContentInfo())
                    assert content['contentType'] == rfc2315.envelopedData

                    myenvelop, rest = decode(content['content'], asn1Spec=rfc2315.EnvelopedData())

                    lenencryptedkey=len(myenvelop['recipientInfos'][0]['encryptedKey'])
                    #print(lenencryptedkey)
                    encryptedsessionkey=myenvelop['recipientInfos'][0]['encryptedKey']
                    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
                    try:

            #this next line is a command to decrypt the encrypted AES session key with the private key.
                    decryptedsessionkey=private_key.decrypt(bytes(encryptedsessionkey), padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), label=None))
```

I  get this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/VoxaiLap10/Desktop/pythonbible/cryptotest7-23-18_testpart1.py", line 111, in <module>
    decryptedsessionkey=private_key.decrypt(bytes(encryptedsessionkey), padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), label=None))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\rsa.py", line 362, in decrypt
    return _enc_dec_rsa(self._backend, self, ciphertext, padding)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\rsa.py", line 68, in _enc_dec_rsa
    return _enc_dec_rsa_pkey_ctx(backend, key, data, padding_enum, padding)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\rsa.py", line 130, in _enc_dec_rsa_pkey_ctx
    _handle_rsa_enc_dec_error(backend, key)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\rsa.py", line 161, in _handle_rsa_enc_dec_error
    raise ValueError("Decryption failed.")
ValueError: Decryption failed.
```

The error seems to be occurring in the python crypt module, but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong. I've considered the possibility that the private key is not the correct value for the public key that was used to encrypt the session key; do you think this is causing the error?
This is the relevant RSA.py library file from where the error is coming.:

```
    outlen = backend._ffi.new("size_t *", buf_size)
    buf = backend._ffi.new("unsigned char[]", buf_size)
    res = crypt(pkey_ctx, buf, outlen, data, len(data))
    print(buf)
    print(outlen)
    print(data)
    print(len(data))
    print(res)
    if res <= 0:
        _handle_rsa_enc_dec_error(backend, key)

    return backend._ffi.buffer(buf)[:outlen[0]]


def _handle_rsa_enc_dec_error(backend, key):
    errors = backend._consume_errors()
    assert errors
    assert errors[0].lib == backend._lib.ERR_LIB_RSA
    if isinstance(key, _RSAPublicKey):
        assert (errors[0].reason ==
                backend._lib.RSA_R_DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_KEY_SIZE)
        raise ValueError(
            "Data too long for key size. Encrypt less data or use a "
            "larger key size."
        )
    else:
        decoding_errors = [
            backend._lib.RSA_R_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_NOT_01,
            backend._lib.RSA_R_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_NOT_02,
            backend._lib.RSA_R_OAEP_DECODING_ERROR,
            # Though this error looks similar to the
            # RSA_R_DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_KEY_SIZE, this occurs on decrypts,
            # rather than on encrypts
            backend._lib.RSA_R_DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_MODULUS,
        ]
        if backend._lib.Cryptography_HAS_RSA_R_PKCS_DECODING_ERROR:
            decoding_errors.append(backend._lib.RSA_R_PKCS_DECODING_ERROR)

        assert errors[0].reason in decoding_errors
        print(errors[0].reason)
        raise ValueError("Decryption failed.")
```

The `res` value from calling the `crypt` function is -1; do you know what this represents?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic for this site, even if what you are programming is related to cryptography. In particular, you are asking why your Python implementation is throwing an error, which would be far better suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to other sites. You have to be patient with your questions sometimes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is an error thrown in Python cryptography RSA decryption of encrypted AES key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51457881/why-is-an-error-thrown-in-python-cryptography-rsa-decryption-of-encrypted-aes-ke)

Comment: @James K Polk sorry for cross posting; thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

> The res value from calling the crypt function is -1; do you know what this represents?

If python is calling OpenSSL underneath, and the error codes exactly matching OpenSSL's strongly suggest that, [it means any error other than unsupported](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_PKEY_decrypt.html). To get details you need to look at OpenSSL's 'error queue', and presumably `errors = backend._consume_errors()` does exactly that. Although most of the details you can get don't tell you the cause of the problem anyway.

> I've considered the possibility that the private key is not the correct value for the public key that was used to encrypt the session key; do you think this is causing the error?

It certainly could; RSA-decrypting with the wrong key (but of the right size) *either* gives an error for exceeding the modulus or else with overwhelming probability produces effectively random garbage data under the hood which leads to a padding error. You could try looking at RecipientInfo.issuerAndSerialNumber (renamed rid in CMS rfc2630+) to make sure it is or at least looks like the (or a) correct identifier for your key. If there are multiple recipients, you might not be `[0]`.

It could also be wrong scheme; you should check RecipientInfo.keyEncryptionAlgorithm. It could also be wrong (modified or tampered) encrypted data, but it's very unlikely a PEM-formatted message gets accidentally corrupted but still parses, so this would have to be either an attack or a bug in the sender.

Since it's in a file, can you check with commandline `openssl smime -inform pem -decrypt` ?

Comment: thanks for your answer.  The decryption has been completed by adding the encrypted content to the pkcs7 file under field ['encryptedContent'] and then using subprocess from python with the openssl command: openssl smime -decrypt –inform DER -in encryptedFile -inkey pemkeyfile